# Playing badminton after tooth extraction

Tags: sports, tooth-decay, tooth-extraction

Is it advisable to play badminton after having a simple tooth extraction for one of my wisdom teeth?

I have a tournament (I will be playing around 5 matches, I'm an intermediate player) in the coming 3 days and I am planning to get one of my tooth extracted before 2 days of the tournament, as it is causing pain.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

That will be hard to predict, as it varies from person to person. I've had one of them extracted and could train the next day (a different sport, korfball, but with similar impact on your body as badminton); a team mate couldn't play for a week after his operation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impacted_wisdom_teeth#Wisdom_teeth_removal) states

> Most patients will experience pain and swelling (worst on the first post-operative day) then return to work after 2 to 3 days

but also

> the rate of discomfort decreased to about 25% by post-operative day 7

so don't expect the operation to help so soon; it will mostly have a long term effect.